# Alternative to node's EventEmitter for use in reactjs.NET

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs.net

I'm trying to implement flux architecture for a react.js application.  I am using ReactJS.NET and not node, which means that I don't have access to node's Event Emitter system.

The example I am trying to emulate is here: https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-todomvc/js/stores/TodoStore.js

Is there another library I could use that would achieve the same effect which doesn't require nodejs?

Comment: Have you tried using Browserify or Webpack to pull in an event emitter module from NPM (or Node.js' EventEmitter)? Alternatively you could just create a simple one yourself :)

Comment: Daniel.  I will try that, however, this seems to work well: https://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter